# Indoor path-finding c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, path-finding

I am currently developing an indoor path-finding. I have multiple floors and different rooms. How will I be able to implement a* algorithm in the images of each floor using c# wpf?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Cutie. I am afraid this question is way too broad for SO. Please refer to [ask] , take the [tour] and break up your question into answerable questions.

Comment: wpf is the framework for user interfaces, therefore I don't think it applies to the implementation of a*

Answer (score 1):

I use spatial A* for the game I'm working on.

Spatial A* uses movement "cost" to work out the best route between two points.  The cost mentions is supplied by an array. Usually a 2d array of number - float uint or whatever.

Moving through a square/cell at position x,y thus costs the number in that 2d array. EG costs[2,3] would be the cost of movement through the cell 2 cells across from the left and 3 down from the top of an imaginary grid projected onto your "room".

If the move is diagonal then there's also a multiplier to consider but that will be in whichever implementation you go with.

Hence you need a 2d costed array per floor.

You would need to somehow analyse your pictures and work out an appropriate size for a costed cell.  This should match the smallest size of a significant piece of terrain in your floor.

You would then translate your picture into a costed array. You've not told us anywhere near enough to tell you specifically how to do that. Maybe that would have to be a manual process though.

Blocked cells get the max number, empty cells get 1.  Depending on your requirements that might be that. Or alternatively you might have actors leaping tables and chairs etc.

You give the pathing algorithm start and target location (x,y), the appropriate costed array and it works out the cheapest route.